# WFS - MapServer - ASP.NET

Tags: mapserver, asp.net, mapscript

Nowadays i'm working with Mapcript / Mapserver. I would like to know how to used WFS (Web Feature Service) with ASP.NET.

I think i need to use WCF, right?
Is there any tutorial or framework?

Comment: You don't need WCF to use Mapscript. You need Mapserver and IIS to run C# Mapscript.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:
http://www.paolocorti.net/2006/09/20/mapserver-tutorial-for-c-mapscript-asp-net/

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many ways. Personally i use [openlayers javascript api](http://openlayers.org/) to query everything i need from my WFS service. Then you can pass this information onto the backend (.NET).

Comment: Ok! I think this is the way, but how can i implement WFS in .NET?

Comment: By implement do you mean call?

Comment: http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs

Comment: I mean, how to expose the proprieties of my map by mapscript/mapserver using WCF. There is a pattern, right?

By WFS you mean using WCF?

Comment: Ahh i see. I don't know... i only know how to do it using GeoServer. Someone else will need to step in and help you. Sorry.

Comment: Wait, I RE-READ your comments and now i'm very confused. Can you give a little background as to what you (or application) are trying to accomplish? Because I don't see why you would want to create a WCF web Service to expose WFS properties from your MapServer if your MapServer already does that. (http://mapserver.org/ogc/wfs_server.html) I must not understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok! My intesion is to used Openlayers as a interface for Mapserver, but there is some points:

in this way: mapserver.org/ogc/wfs_server.htm, i'll need a dedicate server, beacause i'll need to install Mapserver on the server.

But in this way: http://mapserver.org/ogc/mapscript.html, i can use Mapscript, wich is a plugin and has the ability to invoke MapServer’s ability to execute OGC Web Service requests such as WMS, WCS, and WFS,  so i can use it in any server.

Comment: There are others points, with WFS manage for ASP.NET i can have a better control over the request and more security.

Comment: I see...so it looks like you've figured out the answer to your question?

Comment: Actually i didn't, i still need to figure out a way to use Mapcript with ASP.NET WCF. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Mapserver already accept calls like any webserver. You don't need to wrap it up in another webserver. I'm not sure why you need WCF in this picture.